# How can I segment a cloud if I know the rough shape it has to have?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am trying to segment this 3D point cloud (this is the view at the top):

[image]

I want the "inner ellipsis", basically excluding the long red line on the right and some of the other points that stick out too much from the red ellipsis.

How/can I do this with PCL?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using RANSAC but creating your own "elipse" model similar to the models used here: http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/a02954.html. Having done that I am sure it could be of benefit to others too.

Take a look at the code for e.g. SampleConsensusModelPlane or SampleConsensusModelCylinder for an idea how to build such a model:

```
$ cd ~/software/pcl
$ find . -name "sac_model_cylinder*"
./sample_consensus/src/sac_model_cylinder.cpp
./sample_consensus/include/pcl/sample_consensus/impl/sac_model_cylinder.hpp
./sample_consensus/include/pcl/sample_consensus/sac_model_cylinder.h
```

Well, that's probably how I would do it (I haven't done it).

Comment: Note that something like MLESAC might be a bit more forgiving of slight deviations from ellipse shape; this algorithm is available in PCL in the same way that RANSAC is; algorithms and models are supposed to be interchangeable (that's how it looks).

Answer (score 0):

I would try [RANSAC](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cylinder_segmentation.php#cylinder-segmentation) first, and then play with the parameters of the algorithm.

You can also try filtering the cloud a bit (again, try to play with parameters):

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/remove_outliers.php#remove-outliers

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php#statistical-outlier-removal

Comment: I tried RANSAC already, but it filters out either too few or too many points and it makes my convex hull calculation imprecise. I would like to maintain that ellipse-like shape as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the radius of a rough circle that you are interested the data inside, why don't you apply a pass through filter to remove the unwanted parts. Check this [link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php).
Pass through filter can be applied to different fields (x,y,z) and also to colors in RGB or HSI color space ranges.